# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar datos en pantalla?

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy haciendo esto, por ende me aparece un error:

```
SELECT A.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO AS NOMBRE_EDIFICIO
    ,P.NOMBRE_COMUNA
    ,TO_CHAR(P.ADM_NUMRUN, '99G999G999') || '-' || P.ADM_DVRUN RUT_ADMINISTRADOR
    ,P.ADM_PNOMBRE || ' ' | | P.ADM_SNOMBRE || ' ' || P.ADM_APELLIDO_PATERNO || ' ' || P.ADM_APELLIDO_MATERNO AS NOMBRE_ADMINISTRADOR
    ,COUNT(TOTAL_DORMITORIOS) TOTAL_DEPARTAMENTOS
FROM DEPARTAMENTO A
INNER JOIN ADMINISTRADOR P ON A.ID_EDIFICIO = P.ADM_NUMRUN
GROUP BY A.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO
    ,TO_CHAR(P.ADM_NUMRUN, '99G999G999') || '-' || P.ADM_DVRUN
    ,P.ADM_PNOMBRE || ' ' | | P.ADM_SNOMBRE || ' ' || P.ADM_APELLIDO_PATERNO || ' ' || P.ADM_APELLIDO_MATERNO
ORDER BY NOMBRE_COMUNA
    ,NOMBRE_EDIFICIO
```

Estoy ocupando Oracle SQL Developer y recibo este error:

> ORA-00904: "P"."NOMBRE_COMUNA": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" *Cause: *Action: Error en la línea: 22, columna: 10

Aquí me aparece error por ende quiero mostrar el edificio el rut del administrador los datos del administrador y contar cuantos departamentos hay.

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? Hay que verificar si los espacios en el operador de concatencación son errores al copiar o si son parte de la consulta real. ¿Estás usando Oracle (según lo que indica el código) o SQL Server (según la etiqueta que usaste)?

Comment: ORA-00904: "P"."NOMBRE_COMUNA": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error en la línea: 22, columna: 10 aqui me aparece error por ende quiero mostrar el edificio el rut del administrador los datos del administrador y contar cuantos departamentos hay

Comment: ¿Existe la columna `NOMBRE_COMUNA` en la tabla `ADMINISTRADOR`?

Comment: la tengo que juntar con la tabla de administrador o edificio una de esas dos son

Comment: esto me piden El informe debe indicar el nombre del edificio, la comuna en la cual se ubica, run y nombre completo del administrador, el total de departamentos que posee el edificio y cuántos departamentos no han pagado los gastos comunes. La información se requiere en el formato que se indica en el ejemplo y ordenada alfabéticamente por comuna y nombre del edificio. El informe del ejemplo se ejecutó el último día hábil de Agosto del presente año por lo tanto, está mostrando el total de departamentos que no pagaron los gastos comunes de Julio del presente año:

Comment: Entendido lo que te piden. Cuáles son las tablas de las que tomas los datos? Por favor, añade como texto la definición de esas tablas.

Comment: me piden los nombres de los edificios, la comuna,los datos del rut y el nombre completo del administradror, la cantidad de departamentos y el total de departamentos que no fueron cancelados ;ADM_NUMRUN,ADM_DVRUN,ADM_PNOMBRE,ADM_SNOMBRE,ADM_APELLIDO_PATERNO,ADM_APELLIDO_MATERNO es la del administrador,NOMBRE_COMUNA esa es de la tabla comuna ,TOTAL_DORMITORIOS esa la saque para contar los departamentos (departamentos),EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO esa es la del edificio y el conteo de los departamentos q no fueron cancelados no se como la  puedo sacar

Comment: si quieres te mando el scrips